# I need help resolving 'JavaScript heap out of memory' of my GatsbyJS build on Ubuntu 20

Tags: node.js, wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I need help fixing my failing GatsbyJS build.

I got following function running in gatsby-node.js when running a build pipeline in Jenkins on Ubuntu. Unfortunately the build is failing in the 'gatsby build' step and are producing following message;  *"FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"*

Node version I am running with on Ubuntu is 17.2.0.

The function run is listed below:

```
exports.createPages = async function ({ graphql, actions }) {

const { createPage } = actions

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  graphql(
        `{
            allWpPage {
                edges {
                    node {
                        date
                        content
                        title
                        slug
                        id
                    }
                }
            }
        }`
    ).then(result => { // ==== PAGES ====
        if (result.errors) {
            console.log(result.errors)
            reject(result.errors)
        }

        const pageTemplate = path.resolve("./src/templates/Page.jsx")

        _.each(result.data.allWpPage.edges, edge => {
            createPage({
                path: `/${edge.node.slug}/`,
                component: slash(pageTemplate),
                context: edge.node,
            })
        })
    }).then(() => { // ==== SHARES ====
        graphql(
            `{
                allWpShare {
                    edges {
                        node {
                        modified
                        date
                        content
                        excerpt
                        id
                        status
                        title
                        slug
                        shareInformation {
                            company
                            country
                            currency
                            sector
                            shares
                            stockExchange
                            ticker
                        }
                        featuredImage {
                            node {
                                    altText
                                    caption
                                    description
                                    fileSize
                                    id
                                    link
                                    slug
                                    sourceUrl
                                    title
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }`
        ).then(result => {
            if (result.errors) {
                console.log(result.errors)
                reject(result.errors)
            }
        
            const ShareTemplate = path.resolve("./src/templates/Share.jsx")
            
            _.each(result.data.allWpShare.edges, edge => {
                createPage({
                    path: `/share/${edge.node.slug}/`,
                    component: slash(ShareTemplate),
                    context: edge.node,
                })
            })
        })
    }).then(() => { // ==== POSTS ====
        graphql(
            `{
                allWpPost {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            modified
                            date
                            content
                            excerpt
                            id
                            status
                            tags {
                                nodes {
                                    slug
                                    name
                                    id
                                    description
                                }
                            }
                            title
                            slug
                            featuredImage {
                                node {
                                    slug
                                    id
                                    altText
                                    caption
                                    description
                                    fileSize
                                    link
                                    sizes
                                    title
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }`
        ).then(result => {
            if (result.errors) {
                console.log(result.errors)
                reject(result.errors)
            }
    
            const postTemplate = path.resolve("./src/templates/Post.jsx")
            
            _.each(result.data.allWpPost.edges, edge => {
                createPage({
                    path: `/post/${edge.node.slug}/`,
                    component: slash(postTemplate),
                    context: edge.node,
                })
            })
        })
    })
    resolve()
})}
```

I am quite convinced that the out-of-memory problem is caused by the amount of nodes run in this function. If I strip away the two last fetch parts of the promise, the build is successfull. Below is the function that compiles succesfully:

```
exports.createPages = async function ({ graphql, actions }) {

const { createPage } = actions

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  graphql(
        `{
            allWpPage {
                edges {
                    node {
                        date
                        content
                        title
                        slug
                        id
                    }
                }
            }
        }`
    ).then(result => { // ==== PAGES ====
        if (result.errors) {
            console.log(result.errors)
            reject(result.errors)
        }

        const pageTemplate = path.resolve("./src/templates/Page.jsx")
        
        _.each(result.data.allWpPage.edges, edge => {

            createPage({
                path: `/${edge.node.slug}/`,
                component: slash(pageTemplate),
                context: edge.node,
            })
        })

        resolve()
    })
})}
```

I have tried increasing the RAM space size of Nodejs, but that does not fix the out-of-memory problem.

The build do also completes successfully localy on my own machine.

I have used the same function successfully in other GatsbyJS project, but not this time. I have tried to fix the problem myself, but are now out of good ideas.

Maybe someone here can help me out?

Comment: ` I strip away the two last fetch parts of the promise` - can you mark them in the question? It will be easy for readers to see. Also, what node version are you using? WHen you run the code on local does it work?

Comment: Hi Apoorca Chikara
Thank you for your comment and questions. I have updated the post with the details you are requesting.

Comment: "I have tried increasing the RAM space size of Nodejs," How you'e tried it?

Comment: Using the following: NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=16384 --optimize_for_size --max_executable_size=4096 --stack_size=4096"